# Google App Engine VS Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

I want to create an application using java. It will be a web based application. Can any one please tell me which one is better Google App Engine or Cloud Foundry. And it will be very helpful for me if you tell me the difference between those two.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question can't possibly be answered in an appropriate way. Read the descriptions of the services and check if they meet the requirements of your project. We don't know what's better for *you*. So please, do some research first and come back if you have any specific questions about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some very good comparison:
http://cloudcomputing.sys-con.com/node/2265743

But it really depends on your needs- what type of web application you use? are you using eclipse (don't know about Cloud Foundry, but app engine have a very good plugin)?
performance, DB or big tables, management, number of users and many more.